# Dom element change notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging, google-chrome

I am having the weirdest of problems. In chrome browser alone, one of my html divs get an additional inline css tag added to it. This tag is `style="overflow:hidden"`, this was causing the layout to break and we quick found out this was the problem.

However there is no place in the codebase that we could search which lets us know how this tag is getting added. is there a way to debug this? I tried the chrome javascript debugger but it did not help me find the issue. In all other browsers the tag does not appear. In chrome it appends itself to a div element. We tried searching on the div element assuming that jquery/javascript is doing a late manipulation of the element but still cannot find where it is happening.

Is there a watch we can set on an element to see when it is changing or who is manipulating it?

Comment: can you post a link to your page? or try to duplicate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: This is the perfect time to use a divide and conquer strategy: start removing large pieces and seeing if the problem is still exhibited until you can narrow down smaller and smaller chunks that affect the presence of the unwanted behavior. I'd start by removing the javascript from the page and if that stops the behavior, override the jQuery hide method and have it raise an error (that'll dump a stacktrace in your console).

Comment: Is your `DIV` has an `id` or css `class` already defined ? If yes you could you add `overflow:scroll !important;` in the css rules

Comment: my div has a class called 'control' in FF the html code is `<div class='control'>` but in chrome the code becomes `<div class='control' style='overflow:hidden'>`. The control class is a simple class which only sets the foreground and background color

Comment: Then if you have access to the css file you just need to add 'overflow:scroll !important;' in the class `control` and it will override it.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment you can override the class `control`in your `css` file.

```
.control{
    overflow:auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm! Obviously you could step through the javascript that is on your page.

To rule out javascript you could try disabling javascript totally. Or add an inline style with

```
overflow: auto!important
```

to the  div  element

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help with the information provided but what you can do is add `overflow: visible !important;` to that `.control`. Check this out in the console and you will see this overrides the inline hidden style

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/twvyq/2/)